# PHP Logging in and Handling Session Security

Tags: php, mysql, security, session

I'm working on a community page and I've looked at a lot of the things surrounding security with logging in, but I'm still confused with how to secure the session. The only thing I do after a successful login is set `$_SESSION['username']` to their username.

Users register and I use prepared statements to insert into the database. Password is stored using

```
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT).
```

Login grabs the hashed password from the database and uses

```
password_verify($password, $storedPassword)
```

If password_verify is true I set their username in a session token. Should I be doing more? Should I be storing the password in the session too? And constantly checking to make sure those two tokens match on every page?

Thanks in advance for your help, I found a lack of information available for how to handle post login security.

Comment: session data is kept server-side. you shouldn't have to do anything to "secure" it, unless you're on a shared server. the only way a user can change the session data is by using your code - so if your code is "secure", then session is "secure" as well.

Comment: Thanks Marc, this is why I was only doing something this simple. Everything I found while searching said that it was not possible to spoof a session. I have a hard time believing it can be this simple though...

Comment: it's possible to steal/spoof the session COOKIE, but directly modifying the data stored in $_SESSION means your server and/or site have been compromised anyways.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set the password to session.Nobody can steals your information because php is a server scripting language. Once session has been started your PHP code will handles it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

My company has published two blog posts about this subject, in a way. One is about [safe and secure PHP sessions](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/fast-track-safe-and-secure-php-sessions) and the other is about [user authentication with remember me cookies](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence).

The short answer is that the data stored in session variables is essentially private. You can just store a row ID and username and call it a day. Your security should focus on controlling what goes into `$_SESSION`, not verifying what's already there.